# :before content displays different when defined in CSS

Tags: html, css

I found [this](https://fribly.com/2015/01/01/scalable-responsive-progress-bar/) nice progress bar which I'm currently trying to customize.

The original is pulling CSS `content` values from an html attribute like this:

```
<li class]="is-active" data-step="1">Patient Screening</li>

&:before {
    content: attr(data-step);
}
```

In my code, I'd like to just define the content in CSS.  When I attempt to do this, though, the step circle bumps down.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWdzyN) is a CodePen.

Comment: Is that SASS? Add the tag for whatever pre-processor that is. Also, you need to post your code here, not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.progress > li`. You're using tables, and that will fix your problem.

[New CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWpELO)

Comment: Whoops! there you go.